# How to get metadata from a link

Tags: php, jquery, silverstripe

I am looking to implement a solution on a website that will allow the user to **post a link** and once posted the link will **expand content** like it would on **Facebook** or **Linkedin** for example.

I.e. 'Title', 'Short Description', 'Image'.

How could I achieve this?

Comment: any code you have put together already?

Comment: Not any yet, i've searched around google but i'm not sure if there is a specific term I am missing as to why i'm not receiving any results I want. Thanks.

Comment: The logic behind the very thing is to get the link content fetch on your server and find for Title and an image, then update your item with the data. [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will fetch the data for you and you need to do the rest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP's function `get-meta-tags()` for that.

Example:

```
<?php
// Assuming the above tags are at www.example.com
$tags = get_meta_tags('http://www.example.com/');

// Notice how the keys are all lowercase now, and
// how . was replaced by _ in the key.
echo $tags['author'];       // name
echo $tags['keywords'];     // php documentation
echo $tags['description'];  // a php manual
echo $tags['geo_position']; // 49.33;-86.59
?>
```

See:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-meta-tags.php

Answer (score 0):

The logic behind the very thing is to get the link content fetch on your server and find for Title and an image, then update your item with the data. [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) will fetch the data for you and you need to do the rest. –

If you are looking for the specific, there are thousand of tutorials. Find one below.

http://www.sanwebe.com/2013/06/extract-url-content-like-facebook-with-php-and-jquery